# How can i solve my camera smooth movement error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I've been trying a new method I found about camera movement (Im trying to do like a metroidvania) and i just made a script that makes the camera size a collider so the camera can only move across it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform player;
    private BoxCollider2D camBox;
    private GameObject[] boundaries;
    private Bounds[] allBounds;
    private Bounds targetBounds;

    public float speed;
    private float waitForSeconds = 0.5f;

    void start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
        camBox = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        FindLimits();
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if(waitForSeconds > 0)
        {
            waitForSeconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        }else{
            SetOneLimit();
            FollowPlayer();
        }
    }

    //Encuentra el encaje de la camara
    void FindLimits() 
    {
        boundaries = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Boundary");
        allBounds = new Bounds[boundaries.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < allBounds.Length; i++)
        {
            allBounds[i] = boundaries[i].gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds; 
        }
    }
    //Ajusta la medida de la camara al borde
    void SetOneLimit()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < allBounds.Length; i++)
        {
            if(player.position.x > allBounds[i].min.x && player.position.x < allBounds[i].max.x && player.position.y > allBounds[i].min.y && player.position.y < allBounds[i].max.y)

            {
                targetBounds = allBounds[i];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    void FollowPlayer()
    {
        float xTarget=camBox.size.x<targetBounds.size.x?Mathf.Clamp(player.position.x, targetBounds.min.x+camBox.size.x/2, targetBounds.max.x-camBox.size.x/2):(targetBounds.min.x+targetBounds.max.x)/2;
        float yTarget=camBox.size.y<targetBounds.size.y?Mathf.Clamp(player.position.y, targetBounds.min.y+camBox.size.y/2, targetBounds.max.y-camBox.size.y/2):(targetBounds.min.y+targetBounds.max.y)/2;
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(xTarget, yTarget, transform.position.z);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This is the code that im using and this is the error that I get when pressing the play button.

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

**CameraFollow.SetOneLimit () (at Assets/Scripts/CameraFollow.cs:46)**

**CameraFollow.LateUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/CameraFollow.cs:28)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`start()` is written lower case, I'm not sure it will be work same as `Start()` ;)
Check it because probably your field aren't initialized propertly.

And read some about NullReferenceException ;)